# Delete command under AFP 18.04, 16.x, 14.x on DSM

Tags: networking, nas, smb

just upgraded to 18.04 and the delete command does not work on my NAS.

Synology NAS
DSM 6.2-23739 Update 2
Model DS115j

any ideas on how to start debugging?

(not a rights issue - all works with same ID under WIN 10)

Here is a step by step description of what I am experiencing.

Boot machine

Select Files icon from tray

From options with File window select last option:
“+  Other Locations”

At that point there are options for selecting:
“On This Computer”
and 
“Networks”

Under Networks there are three icons.

The first two Icons are identical and resemble three stacked gray hard drive enclosures both are labeled: “My1NAS (file Sharing)”

The third Icon is a yellow/orange folder labeled:
“Windows Networks”

If I select the first Icon I get window prompt labeled:
“Enter your name and password for the server “My1NAS”

And an input for: “Username”
And an input for: “Password”

There are also three button labeled:
“Forget password immediately”
“Remember password until you logout”
“Remember forever”

I select:
“Remember password until you logout” (default)
and enter a username and password (account with full rights to NAS)

Then press “Connect”

Then navigate to the folder I am working on (3 levels down)

Right click select a file
Select “Delete Permanently”
Confirm “Are you sure you want to permanently delete “myfile.NEF?”
“if you delete an item, it will be permanently lost.”

The file appears have been deleted.  However, move in and out of folder and the file re-appears.

Just to be clear, I can rename a file, move it, copy files to and from folder, just not delete it.

Under Windows 10 I have no problems.

Everything under 16.0? worked.
This happens under other apps under 18.04

The only thing that seems perhaps strange is that DMS shows the connection type as AFP.  (although I am not sure it was APF under 16.0? as well.)

***UPDATE:***
I worked with Synology for a while on this issue.  I think that there is a bug in 18.x and 16.x and perhaps other release (i.e. 14.04.x LTS) when you connect under AFP to a DSM device.  (I had incorrectly thought that the problem did not exist under 16.x.  It does exist.) You cannot delete a file by right clicking on it and selecting delete.  It appears to go away, but a refresh shows that it is still there.  However, select the file with your mouse, and use the "delete" button on your keyboard - and you do in fact delete it.   (Under other Apps like FSlint the delete command fails – which is what started this whole thing for me.)  Under SMB there are no deletion problems, however, if you try to re-name a file you get an "invalid argument", however, the files does get renamed.  The reason that this became a problem for me is that for me under 14.x the first icon under Files –> Other Locations was for an SMB connection.  Under 16.x and 18.x the first icon is for an AFP connection.  The icons look the same, and I wasn’t paying attention and just selected the “default” top icon.  Beside this update, I am not sure what else to do with this information.  Suggestions welcome.

Comment: What "delete" command, and how does it fail, exactly?

Comment: updated comment

Comment: Worked with Synology for a while one this.